# Replay stimulus multiple times in PsychoPy

Tags: psychopy

I'm building an experiment where in each trial, the subjects can replay stimulus as many times as they wish by pressing certain keys.
For example, there're 2 sounds: s1 and s2. s1 is associated with key 'a', and s2 is associated with key 'j'. Whenever the subject presses 'a', s1 will be played. Same for s2. Space bar is used to terminate the present trial and jump to the next trial.

Now I'm able to play stimulus after key press, by having '$event.getKeys('a')' in the condition field in s1 sound component, and '$event.getKeys('j')' in s2 sound component. But this will only play each stimulus once in a trial. The second time the keys are pressed, there are no sounds.

So my question is, what should I do so that in each trial, a stimulus can be played EACH time a designated key is pressed?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Builder sound component is not ideal for this: as you noticed, if a condition is specified for the onset, it can only trigger the sound once per trial.

An alternative is to create a non-graphical sound object in a code component, and then check for key presses on every frame of each trial, and trigger the sound as required. Insert a Code component. In the "Begin Experiment" tab, put something like this:

```
j_sound = sound.Sound(u'A', secs=0.5) 
a_sound = sound.Sound(u'B', secs=0.5)
```

Then, in the "Each frame" tab, put something like this:

```
response = event.getKeys(keyList=['a','j'])
if 'a' in response:
    a_sound.play()
elif 'j' in response:
    j_sound.play()
```

This could be improved to handle key presses made while a sound is already playing, but should get you started.

Comment: Do you mean that I don't need to create a graphic sound object and just need to write the above in to a code component? In this case, how should I specify the sounds I want to play? That is, what should I put in place of u'A'? I'm sorry that I have don't know much about writing python scripts

Comment: Yes, you can create sounds purely in code, as above, and then refer to them by name later on. You haven't said what sounds you want to play so I can't tell you how to specify them. Look at the PsychoPy sound API docs here: <http://www.psychopy.org/api/sound.html> to see how the value can be specified: as a note name (in the example above, 'A'), or by frequency, sound filename, etc.

Comment: So there'll be different stimuli in different trials, and I have a csv file that contains the file names for each trial. Is there a way to specify a file name from the csv file in code?

Comment: Yes. Shift the sound creation lines from the "Begin Experiment" tab to the "Begin Routine" tab so that a new one is created each trial. They will look something like this: "j_sound = sound.Sound(value=jFileName)", where jFileName is the name of the column in your CSV file that contains the relevant filenames. Do the same for the other sound, which will have its own column for filenames.

Comment: Also remember to tick this as an answer if it does what you need: it helps anyone else in the future who comes across this.